# When the measure is only defined for a generating collection, does the measure actually exist?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set. Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ and let $\mathcal F$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $S$, i.e. $\sigma(S)=\mathcal F$. Let $\mu:S\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ be the function satisfying the following properties:

1. (non-negativity) $\mu(A)\geq0$ for all $A\in S$;
2. (null empty set) $\mu(\phi)=0$ if $\phi\in S$;
3. (countable additivity) $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty \mu(A_i)$ for all at most countable collections $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in S$ such that $A_i\cap A_j=\phi$ whenever $i\neq j$. For finite collections $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\in S$, $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty \mu(A_i)$ becomes $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^n A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n \mu(A_i)$.

Then is there a measure $\tilde\mu:\mathcal F\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ such that $\tilde\mu(A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in S$?

I'm sorry that I can't include my attempt because I don't know where to start.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the measure property"?

Comment: @drhab $\mu$ has the following three properties: 1. (non-negativity) $\mu(A)\geq 0$ for all $A\in S$; 2. (null empty set) $\mu(\phi)=0$ if $\phi\in S$; 3. (countable additivity) $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty \mu(A_i)$ for every at most countable collections $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ such that they are pairwise disjoint. If the collection $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ is finite, then $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty \mu(A_i)$ becomes $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^n A_i) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n \mu(A_i)$. I'll write this in the question.

Comment: Let it be that e.g. $S=\{\varnothing,A,B\}$ where $\varnothing\neq B\subsetneq A$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(\varnothing)=0$ and $\mu(B)=1$. Then all properties that you mention are satisfied, right? But $\mu$ can definitely not be extended to a measure. I think your question needs extra conditions on $S$.

Comment: @drhab I see. Thanks!